# LilyPond: How to add a graphical object (clef)

Tags: lilypond, clefs

I need to add a custom clef symbol instead of the traditional ones.

(The example below I created with Photoshop.)

[image: Score with an unusual clef symbol.]

Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I’m not mistaken, the clef symbol that you want is “ওঁ”.  This is two characters in Unicode (`\char ##x0993` & `\char ##x0981`).  Unfortunately, I can’t figure out how (or if it is possible) to enter Unicode combining characters so that they actually *combine* into one, but you can simply enter this character as text (`ওঁ`).

If you want to *draw* the clef symbol, this can be done by placing the drawing commands inside the `\markup` block instead. (See https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.24/Documentation/notation/graphic.)

Scale the symbol with `\magnify`, set the baseline of the symbol with `\set Staff.clefPosition`, and set the middle-C position with `\set Staff.middleCPosition`.

#### Code

```
\version "2.24.1"

omClef = {
    \override Staff.Clef.stencil = #ly:text-interface::print
    \override Staff.Clef.text = \markup { 
        \magnify #1.85 {
            ওঁ
        }
    }
    \set Staff.clefPosition = -4
    \set Staff.middleCPosition = -6
}

\new Staff {
    \omClef 
    \key ges \major
        ges'1 |
        des'8 ees' f'8 8 8 8 8 8 |
}
```

#### Image

[image: Rendering of the above code, showing the custom Om clef]

Answer (score 5):

Some slight formatting changes to Elements’ solution:

```
#(define-markup-command (magnify-to layout props target mup) (number? markup?)
   (let* ((stc (interpret-markup layout props mup))
          (stc-ext-y (ly:stencil-extent stc Y))
          (stc-h (interval-length stc-ext-y)))
     (ly:stencil-scale stc (/ target stc-h) (/ target stc-h))))

omClef = {
    \override Staff.Clef.stencil = #ly:text-interface::print
    \override Staff.Clef.text = \markup {
        \magnify-to #4 \vcenter {
            ওঁ
        }
    }
    \set Staff.clefPosition = 0
    \set Staff.middleCPosition = -6
}
```

This will scale the glyph to correct size and center it instead of manually trying to find a good scale and abusing clef position for centering. As none of the Lilypond fonts provides this glyph rendering will use a fallback which depends on your system. It might be good to choose a font which provides a glyph you like and spcfify that glyph by doing say `\override #'(font-name . "Noto Serif")`.